# Echo a single value only

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo

So, I have some PHP that includes this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $wealth = $row['wealth'];
    echo $wealth;
}
```

I assign the value of 'data' to a variable, 'x', and when I do alert(x) the following shows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
136</body>
</html>
```

While I just want it to output

```
136
```

Here's my javascript code:

```
var username=localStorage.getItem('userName');
var highscore;

function getHighScore(user){
    $.get("getScore.php?userName="+user,function(data){
        console.log(data);
                highscore=data;
                alert(highscore);

    });
}

getHighScore(username);
```

Full PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$username = strval($_GET['userName']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','XXXX','XXXX','XXXX');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} else {
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $wealth = $row['wealth'];

    echo $wealth;

    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
//return $wealth;
?></body>
</html>
```

Comment: please show your javascript code

Comment: What else is the php file doing? I suspect the php file is also returning html. Please share the code from php file.

Comment: @NawedKhan Done. PHP retrieves a value from a column in a MySQL database. 'data' should be the value of $wealth, because we echoed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the html code from your php. Everything before ?php and after ?

You are returning all the html from php and the javascript is showing it.

Comment: You are welcome. Usually JSON, or even better JSONP, should be used for this purpose. Specially if you wish to return more than one value in a more structured way.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Below Code

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $wealth = $row['wealth'];
}

print_r($wealth);
```

I think it's works. if not comment below.